# WFC application on a local computer

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a WinForms application that accesses about 80 WCF services. These services are hosted on a web server.

Now I have to change this application to run 100% locally on a computer.

What is the easiest way to do this without having to install IIS on a local computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

there are [4 hosting options for WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

1. Self hosting
2. Windows Service
3. IIS
4. WAS (Windows process activation service)

It's been my experience that self hosting is easy enough to set up quickly, and flexible enough to change later.

Comment: I second the Self Hosting option. Either with a basic HTTP binding, or netNamedPipes. Works great. Just be sure to keep the hosts on a separate set of threads so you don't bog down the UI.

Comment: Thanks! I will try Self hosting!